# How to determine if a string is a valid PCI address?

Tags: pci, pci-bus

PCI addresses adhere to the [BDF notation](https://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Bus:Device.Function_(BDF)_Notation.)

What would be a good way to determine if a string contains a valid PCI address? 
Any programming language would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with the following regex (javascript) to cover the basic BDF:

```
^([a-fA-F0-9]{2}|[a-fA-F0-9]{4}):[a-fA-F0-9]{2}\.[a-fA-F0-9]{1,2}$
```

extending it to cover the extended versions of BDF should not be that hard.